# non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers (C programming)

Tags: c

Okay so I'm writing a code for class and I think everything is right except I'm getting errors on the printf statements I'm not sure how to do c code and my teacher makes us teach ourselves. I'm getting an undeclared identifier error as well as a non ASCII characters error on the printf statements can someone help me figure out why I'm getting these errors? I just want them to print out that statement word for word so why is it trying to read it as something different?

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum{false, true} bool;

bool is_little_endian()
{
    int x = 1;
   char *y = (char*)&x;
    return 1;
}

unsigned int merge_bytes( unsigned int x, unsigned int y )
{
    return (y & 0xffffff00) | (x & 0xff);
}

unsigned int replace_byte (unsigned int x, int i, unsigned char b)
{

int shift = (b << (8 * i));
int mask = 0xff << shift;
return (~mask & x) | shift;
}

int main()
{
if( is_little_endian() )
{
printf(“Your machine is a Little Endian machine\n”);
}

int x = 0x89ABCDEF;
int y = 0x76543210;
printf(“Merged number = 0x%x\n”, merge_bytes(x,y));
unsigned char z= 0x22;
printf(“Replaced number = 0x%x\n”, replace_byte(x,3,z));
return 0;
}
```

And here is the error I'm getting

```
HW3.c:30:8: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and
      identifiers
printf(“Your machine is a Little Endian machine\n”);
       ^
HW3.c:30:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Your'
printf(“Your machine is a Little Endian machine\n”);
        ^
HW3.c:30:52: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and
      identifiers
printf(“Your machine is a Little Endian machine\n”);
                                                 ^
HW3.c:35:8: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and
      identifiers
printf(“Merged number = 0x%x\n”, merge_bytes(x,y));
       ^
HW3.c:35:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Merged'
printf(“Merged number = 0x%x\n”, merge_bytes(x,y));
        ^
HW3.c:35:33: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and
      identifiers
printf(“Merged number = 0x%x\n”, merge_bytes(x,y));
                              ^
HW3.c:37:8: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and
      identifiers
printf(“Replaced number = 0x%x\n”, replace_byte(x,3,z));
       ^
HW3.c:37:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Replaced'
printf(“Replaced number = 0x%x\n”, replace_byte(x,3,z));
        ^
HW3.c:37:35: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and
      identifiers
printf(“Replaced number = 0x%x\n”, replace_byte(x,3,z));
                                ^
9 errors generated.
```

Comment: `(“Your machine is a Little Endian machine\n”);`

Answer (score 18):

Look at `(“Your machine is a Little Endian machine\n”);`. Notice the "curvy quotes": these are clearly not ASCII quotes (which look like this: `"`). You have to replace these with "straight quotes". (This also applies to all of your other strings).

Don't edit code in anything that isn't a proper *text* editor. In particular, don't edit code in e.g. MS Word, WordPad, or a rich-text editor, because you will likely run into funny issues like this.

Answer (score 5):

If you do copy and paste than you can have these problems.
The answer is to delete all the @, ", etc. signs and redo them using your keyboard. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you are  using like MS Word text symbols and these are not allowed in c or in other programming languages ,you know C is case sensitiv  .For example when you are reading pdf document about c programming und you copy some source code und you paste them in text editor or in Compiler you will mostly get those kinds of errors .

ex:char s3 [100] = {'a','b','\0','d'}; //correct

char s3 [] = {’S’,’t’,’u’,’d’,’i’,’\0 ’,’e’,’r’,’e’,’r’};//not allowed

so it is better when you rewrite the codes instead of copying them and paste in editor.